# How to access “Saved Queries” programmatically?

Tags: google-bigquery

In BigQuery Web UI, there is a “Saved Queries” Section.
Is there way to access (read/write) those programmatically?
Any API?

Comment: Subscribe for updates and vote for this feature request: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111961970

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Nope. It's a UI-only feature with a private interface.

**Update 2021:** We recommend using scripts to save and share queries.

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/command-and-control-now-easier-in-bigquery-with-scripting-and-stored-procedures

Comment: we really need this feature.

Comment: Hi Mikhail - any update on this?  Would love to be able to invoke saved queries via the API, but still seems this isnt supported unless I am missing something?

Comment: Still not a public API unfortunately. It helps to know there's demand, though!

Comment: just stumbled upon this as our client requested for this feature specifically. Any roadmap?

Comment: Added a feature request at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111961970

Comment: @JeremyCondit - any update on this? can we expect this to be available?

Comment: We recommend using scripts to save and share queries. https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/command-and-control-now-easier-in-bigquery-with-scripting-and-stored-procedures

Comment: still not helpful

Comment: `Nope. It's a UI-only feature with a private interface. But we'll consider this a feature request!` If this is not relevant anymore, [edit] it out as it gives a contradicting picture.

Comment: Done. It's unlikely we'll open the API and recommend using saved/shared scripts instead.