# How do you run a saved query from Big Query cli and export result to CSV?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a saved query in Big Query but it's too big to export as CSV. I don't have permission to export to a new table so is there a way to run the query from the `bq` cli and export from there?

Answer (score 1):

From the CLI you can't directly access your saved queries as it's a UI-only feature as of now but, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35109451/how-to-access-saved-queries-programmatically) there is a feature request for that.

If you just want to run it once to get the results you can copy the query from the UI and just paste it when using `bq`.

Using the docs [example query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quickstart-command-line#run_a_query) you can try the following with a public dataset:

```
QUERY="SELECT word, SUM(word_count) as count FROM publicdata:samples.shakespeare WHERE word CONTAINS 'raisin' GROUP BY word"
bq query $QUERY > results.csv
```

The output of `cat results.csv` should be:

```
+---------------+-------+
|     word      | count |
+---------------+-------+
| dispraisingly |     1 |
| praising      |     8 |
| Praising      |     4 |
| raising       |     5 |
| dispraising   |     2 |
| raisins       |     1 |
+---------------+-------+
```

Just replace the `QUERY` variable with your saved query.
Also, [take into account](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/enabling-standard-sql#useLegacySql) if you are using Standard or Legacy SQL with the `--use_legacy_sql` flag.

Reference docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference).

Answer (score 0):

Despite what you may have understood from the official documentation, you can get large query results from `bq query`, but there are multiple details you have to be aware of.

To start, here's an example. I got all of the rows of the public table `usa_names.usa_1910_2013` from the public dataset `bigquery-public-data` by using the [following commands](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#bq_query):

```
total_rows=$(bq query --use_legacy_sql=false --format=csv "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_rows FROM \`bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_2013\`;" | xargs | awk '{print $2}');
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false --max_rows=$((total_rows + 1)) --format=csv "SELECT * FROM \`bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_2013\`;" > output.csv
```

The result of this command was a CSV file with 5552454 lines, with the first two containing header information. The number of rows in this table is 5552452, so it checks out.

Here's where the caveats come in to play:

- Regardless of what the [documentation might seem to say](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results#downloading_and_saving_query_results) when it comes to query download limits specifically, those limits seem to only apply to the Web UI, meaning `bq` is exempt from them;
- At first, I was using the Cloud Shell to run this `bq` command, but the number of rows was so big that streaming the result set into it killed the Cloud Shell instance! I had to use a Compute instance with at least the same resources that of an `n1-standard-4` (4vCPUs, 16GiB RAM), and even with all of this RAM, the query took me 10 minutes to finish (note that the query itself runs server-side, it's just a problem of buffering the results);
- I'm manually copy-pasting the query itself, as there doesn't seem to be a way to reference saved queries directly from `bq`;
- You don't have to use Standard SQL, but you *have* to specify `max_rows`, because otherwise it'll only return you 100 rows (100 is the current default value of this argument);
- You'll still be facing the usual [quotas & limits](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas) associated with BigQuery, so you might want to run this as a batch job or not, it's up to you. Also, don't forget that the maximum response size for a query is 128 MiB, so you might need to break the query into multiple `bq query` commands in order to not hit this size limit. If you want a public table that's big enough to hit this limitation during queries, try the `samples.wikipedia` one from `bigquery-public-data` dataset.

I think that's about it! Just make sure you're running these commands on a beefy machine and after a few tries it should give you the result you want!

**P.S.:** There's currently a feature request to increase the size of CSVs you can download from the Web UI. [You can find it here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905482).