# Retrieve Overwritten Saved Query in Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

I accidentally overwrote a saved project query in BQ with a completely unrelated query. I can't find any documentation about retrieving overwritten queries or about any sort of version control. Has anyone done this as well and recovered their query?

Comment: What does "overwritten query" mean?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, "Saved Query" is UI internal feature (see [How to access “Saved Queries” programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35111413/5221944) and there is respective feature request [REST API for Saved Queries](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111961970)), so we really have no way to manage / control this cases

Meantime you can use query history (either in UI or via respective API or in Stackdriver) to locate use of that query and recreate/re-save it again

Comment: Ok, well thank you for your input. It was a coworkers saved query, and looking through the project queries based off of her email and some query text I remember from the query as the filters, I'm not seeing the query. I wonder if she never ran it. I'll have to check with her if she had a local copy saved. Thank you Mikhail. You always seem to answer my BQ questions, so I appreciate how helpful you always are!

Comment: sure. if this query was actually never run - it will not show up in history :o(