# How to run a query in BigQuery with Apps Script and save the results in a table?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a query that is now scheduled and runs every 15 minutes. The result of the query overwrites a table in BigQuery. I want to be able to run my query more often than 15 minutes and especially trigger the run of the query in apps script according to certain events.

I am trying to use BigQuery API but the documentation is not very helpful.

I would like whether to run a saved query with the API or run a query through the API directly and be able to choose where to write the results and also to overwrite the destination table.

Help !!

Comment: I assume either [jobs.query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query) or [jobs.insert](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/insert) method can be used to run queries via Bigquery REST API, nonetheless for saved queries there is no existed particular API method for now, more context find in this Stackoverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35109451/how-to-access-saved-queries-programmatically). Is this something you're looking for?

Comment: I am struggling to run my code and I get the following error: API call to bigquery.jobs.getQueryResults failed with error: Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while getting Drive credentials. I don't know what to do, couldn't find any good documentation that would fix my problem.

Comment: You could probably start a manual run from the [Big Query Transfer Service API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest/v1/projects.locations.transferConfigs/startManualRuns) (that's where the scheduled queries are stored and managed).